# looping function javascript

Tags: javascript

`saveEmail()` (NOT `page.saveEmail()`) isn't being executed in a 3 second loop...

```
            $('input[name="email"]').bind('blur', function () {
                if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
                page.saveEmail();
            }).bind('focus', function(e){
                  timer = setTimeout(function () {
                      function saveEmail () {
                          setTimeout(page.saveEmail, 3000);  
                      }
                      saveEmail();
                  }, 3000);
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` only fires once. If you want it to be executed repeatedly, you either need to set the timer again when it fires, or use `setInterval`.